# Responsibility to store tokens in OAuth 2.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, oauth-2.0

If I am building a library in .NET based on, say FB or Google API, we get an access token (short lived) and a refresh token (long lived).

As a developer who wishes to build such a library, whose responsibility is it to store those tokens?

1. The client library developer
   or
2. The application consuming my library

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would assume the application consuming your library, since the client library doesn't know how the application wants to store the tokens. I've had tokens stored in databases. I've had them retrievable only by web service. I even had some hardcoded for a test application I worked on.

Comment: So lets assume that application consuming my library sends me access token (short lived) and a refresh token (long lived). If token is invalid , i get a new token using refresh token.
Now i need to notify the calling application about same via some property of object.


whats the best way to notify the calling application that token has changed since the last time it was used and that it needs to be updated/saved in calling application DB/cookie or whatever storage means the calling application has.

is this approach right ?

Comment: 1) You could have a send method that returns an ExpiredToken exception. The calling application then has to call the refreshToken method and then call the send method again.

2) Or you could have a callback function that the library calls whenever it needs to update the access token.